# Paper size when using svg package

Tags: paper-size, svg

My texlive debian is set to a4 paper size (paperconf -p a4). Using pdflatex on the following simple document

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

I either get a pdf in a4 size (without the svg package) or letter size (with svg package).

Is this a feature or a bug and how do I fix it?

Comment: latex always defaults to usletter, use `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}` so the pdf size matches.  This is a feature of the graphics package. (Until a driver-specific back end is chosen by graphics, latex can not set the media size as it requires different commands for each back end,)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sort of. Adding [a4paper] to the class fixes it. However my svg package does not seem to have a [nosetpagesize] option.

Comment: You should use `a4paper` always in any case whether or not you are using these packages otherwise the layout is designed for US Letter. svg is only involved because it loads `graphics` so you can pass that option to graphics, but why would you want an incorrect layout?  I just added `nosetpagesize` as a get out for some specialist classes that were taking care of the page size size themselves and needed to disable user access to changing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to @David Carlisle, just pass option `nosetpagesize` to package `graphicx` before loading `svg`. Nevertheless, I **strongly recommend** setting the paper size explicitly with `a4paper`. Otherwise the media size of the document will not match the paper size and an *incorrect layout* will certainly be used.  The output of the given MWE should make this clear.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{nosetpagesize}{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}
pagewidth:pageheight -- 
\ifluatex
\the\pagewidth:\the\pageheight\par
\else
\the\pdfpagewidth:\the\pdfpageheight\par
\fi
paperwidth:paperheight -- \the\paperwidth:\the\paperheight\par
\end{document}
```